# How to make this code center even with both margins set to auto?

Tags: css

So i have this code and for some reason it refuses to center at the bottom of the page even when i set both margins to "auto". I honestly have no idea what else to try.

```
.bottomcenter {
  Position: absolute;
}

.bottomcenter {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Show your markup too. Show your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set an element to `position: fixed;` it jumps out of the page flow, so you can't center it with `margin: auto;` you'll have to use:

```
.bottomcenter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); /*use this if the width of the element is unknown*/
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%); /*use this if the width of the element is unknown*/
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%); /*use this if the width of the element is unknown*/
    transform: translateX(-50%); /*use this if the width of the element is unknown*/
    width: 200px; /*admitting you know the width of the element*/
    margin-left: -100px; /*this is half the with of the element, admitting it is fixed*/
}
```

Comment: Yes this did it! Thank you, i'm just starting to learn this stuff so thats all a little intimating but i'm sure in due time i'll get the hang of it. Thanks man :D

Comment: Don't worry. Lear what css properties take an element out of the flow. There's more of them and learning them will help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `.bottomcenter` in a container div that is full width, and then add `text-align: center` to the wrapper div:

```
<div class="bottomcenterwrap">
    <div class="bottomcenter">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.bottomcenterwrap
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.bottomcenter
{
    ...
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then add `position: fixed` to the wrapper